# Select first QMenu from QMenuBar using ALT key

Tags: c++, qt, qmenubar

I'm having the folowing problem: I want the first QMenu from QMenuBar to be selected when I press the ALT key. 
I saw that if I create a new project and I create some QMenu objects and add them to the QMenuBar I get the desired behavior, but I'm working on a big project and I can't get this to work. Did anybody had this problem, or has an idea what might be causing this?

I've tried to change the NativeMenuBar property but that didn't help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that some of the Widgets that you are using may have some handling of Keyboard Events. Hence in this case the Alt key will be handled by that appropriate widget. Maybe some UI or code will be helpful to track the problem.
Also try clicking on a blank area on your MainWindow and then try pressing the Atl key. (e.g. You could try clicking blank area besides QMenuBar, if you have one in your application.). Then your ALT key-press should be handled by the MenuBar.